# Generate short id in ebean prior save entity to database

Tags: database, ebean, id-generation

I want to get id of entity before it saved to database. If i have EbeanEntity with:

```
@Id private UUID id;
```

and call

```
Ebean.nextId(EbeanEntity.class);
```

return value is very complex(ce9d8486-2128-4a66-bef4-4158b6de2c7e). I need short value, like when i use Long or String as Id(1, 2, 3... etc).
Ebean.nextId javadoc say "This will only work when a IdGenerator is on this bean type such as a DB sequence or UUID.". If i use Long or String as id, Ebean.nextId returns null.
So how can i use "DB sequence" or another way to get short id of item prior save it to database?

Answer (score 0):

You just **can't**. 
You have to save your bean into the database before get the ID back. 
Something like this

```
Ebean.save(Object); 
int id = object.id;
```